# Definition of amenable group

Tags: group-theory, amenability

I have made several attempts at various times to understand the many equivalent definitions of an amenable group. Is the following statement correct?

A group $G$ is amenable if and only if, for any finite subset $X$ of $G$ and any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a finite subset $A$ of the subgroup $\langle X \rangle$ of $G$ generated by $X$, such that $|xA \, \Delta\, A|/|A| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in X$.

Thanks!

Comment: $(\forall \epsilon >0)(\exists X\subseteq ^{ f }G)(\exists A\subseteq ^{ f }\left< X \right> )(\forall x\in X)\left(\frac { |Ax\setminus A| }{ |A| } +\frac { |A\setminus Ax| }{ |A| } <\epsilon\right)$!? I think there is a relation between this and big/small/skinny sets in a group.

Comment: The standard Følner definition of amenable exactly what you write with "of the subgroup $\langle X\rangle$" erased. So what you write is a priori slightly stronger. But if $G$ is amenable, given finite $X$, given that $\langle X\rangle$ is amenable, you get the property as you write.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

As Yves Cornulier notes, your condition implies the [Følner condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_group) which is the same as yours, but with the condition $A \subseteq \langle X \rangle$ removed.

Conversely, suppose $G$ is amenable. Then the subgroup $H = \langle X \rangle$ is amenable and if $(F_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a [Følner sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folner_sequence) for $H$ then choosing $n$ large enough allows us to take $A = F_n$.

An advantage of your condition is that it is immediately clear that a subgroup of a group satisfying your condition also satisfies your condition. To show that the usual Følner condition passes to subgroups requires an additional argument.

Comment: Thanks to you and Yves for your help!

Comment: By the way, that the Følner condition passes to subgroups can be seen directly. Its negation is the isoperimetric inequality: $\exists S$ finite and $e>0$ such that for every finite $F$ there exists $s\in S$ such that $\#(sF\Delta F)\ge e\#(F)$. Then it's easy that this negative condition passes to overgroups, just partitioning $F$ according to the left cosets of the smallest group.